# Cancel makemigrations Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm developping a website in django but yesterday i did bad thing with my models.

I ran the "makemigrations" command but when I tried to do a "migrate" command, it did not work. So, I would like to cancel all my "makemigrations" that are not "migrate".

Is that possible ??
Thanks!

Comment: You will need to edit your migrations manually under your project's apps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the django_migrations table in your database to see what migrations are applied and delete the other ones from yourapp/migrations

Comment: I did it with command showmigrations and yes there is some migrations not applied, so i only need to delete that files ?

Comment: If you delete those not applied files the migrate command will show "No migrations to apply", It will remain as the last time you did makemigrations, migrate.

Comment: But your code will be still changed, if you do makemigrations again you're going to have trouble too.

Comment: don't forget delete or remove dependencies from other migrations